# How do I compare two columns, so that if a cell in one column is in the other, a value populates a different column

Tags: excel

### What I have

Several workbooks with three columns of a variety of text, numbers and blank cells. I'm stripping these out and putting them into one column in a new workbook, converting them to a 7 digit number stored as text so it populates with `0`s in front, and removing the blanks and text values.

I have a workbook with a list of ~310,000 numbers with the same format as above (`0000000`) stored as text. Also in this workbook is a column that I want to populate if the numbers match.

### What I want to do

I want to compare the numbers that I have been stripping out of the separate workbooks, with the workbook containing 310,000 numbers. If a number from the list of stripped out numbers show up in the list of 310k - column A (which they 100% will) I want it to populate column B with `calcs`.

An issue lies where the column that I want to populate if the numbers match is already partially populated and I don't want to overwrite this. As the column may contain `calcs` or other values, if it already contains `calcs` this is fine.

This is a small sample of what I'm dealing with:

`Stripped out numbers   List of 310k, and column B to populate`

[image: Stripped out numbers] [image: List of 310k, and column B to populate]

Comment: Have you tried if & vlookup?

Comment: vlookup is taking absolutely ages, if it's the only way then I might have to stick to it. I've only ran it on 400 numbers so far and i'm expecting the final list for me to check is going to be around 5,000. I'm not sure how to write the if part into it?

Comment: Oh yea, that's too much calculations. Guess you need a loop.

Comment: I agree pnuts INDEX MATCH will be good to go :)

Comment: Consider turning automatic calculation off in your workbook; this would allow you to work on other items without Excel needing to recalculate this sheet everytime a reference item changes.